# How to reference a libraby that's located in another folder

Tags: c#, .net, dll, c++-cli

I have an application called app1.exe that is calling a function from a dll library called CodeToCall.dll. In the production environment my library is located in another folder that belongs to another program. When I run my application it throws an the following Exception:

> Unhandled Exception: System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'dllToCall, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
>       at main(String[] args)
>       at mainCRTStartupStrArray(String[] arguments)

The Dll I'm referencing is probably using some libraries and they fail to load.

I've tried to including the dll folder in the Windows `PATH` but it didn't succeed, is that the correct way to reference a dll

My `CodeToCall.dll` code:

```
public class Class1
{
    public void Some()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("HI");
    }
}
```

My `app1.exe`, when I added as refernce the `codeToCall.dll`:

```
int main(array<System::String ^> ^args)
{
    //PCWSTR wcstr = L"C:\Program Files(x86)\Sigma"
    Console::WriteLine(L"Hello World");
    dllToCall::Class1^ obj = gcnew class dllToCall:Class1;
    obj->Some();
    Console::ReadKey();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: That depends entirely on how you're loading the `dll`.

Comment: This is not `C#`, you have poor chances to get answer without proper language tag. Also, avoid posting code as image, copying that into answer is .. complicated.

Comment: @Sinatr you're right it's C++/cli but the dll loading mechanism is the same

Comment: It is a simple "file not found" error, very unlikely we can find it for you.  Just make sure that the C# project builds to the same directory as your C++ project.  Use Fuslogvw.exe to troubleshoot.

Answer (score 0):

You can load assemblies from arbitrary folders by subscribing to the [AppDomain::AssemblyResolve](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.appdomain.assemblyresolve.aspx) event. A good overview of assembly resolution is [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff527268.aspx).

In a nutshell:

- The `AppDomain::AssemblyResolve` event will fire when the runtime can't find your referenced assembly in any of the usual places.
- In the event handler, check the event args ([ResolveEventArgs::Name](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.resolveeventargs.name.aspx)) to make sure that .NET is actually asking for the assembly you intend to load.
- In the event handler, it's now up to you to load the assembly, typically using a call to [Assembly::LoadFrom](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.assembly.loadfrom.aspx), which allows you to provide your full path to the CodeToCall.dll).
- If `Assembly::LoadFrom` was successful, it'll return a handle to the newly-loaded assembly. You *must* return that handle from your AssemblyResolve event handler.

(You might be tempted to just call `Assembly::LoadFrom` directly when your app first starts up, but that alone will not work--you *must* return a handle to the assembly from a `AppDomain::AssemblyResolve` handler.)

Example:

```
using namespace System;
using namespace System::Reflection;

Assembly^ MyResolveEventHandler(Object^ sender, ResolveEventArgs^ args)
{
    if (args->Name == "CodeToCall, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null")
        return Assembly::LoadFrom("C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Sigma\\CodeToCall.dll");
    else
        return nullptr;
}

void UseClass1()
{
    auto obj = gcnew CodeToCall::Class1;
    obj->Some();
}

int main(array<System::String ^> ^args)
{
    AppDomain::CurrentDomain->AssemblyResolve += gcnew ResolveEventHandler(MyResolveEventHandler);

    // You can't directly use Class1 in the same method/function
    // that you use to subscribe to AssemblyResolve.
    UseClass1();

    Console::ReadKey();
    return 0;
}
```